# php fatal error with date

Tags: php, datetime

This is my function:

```
public static function GetFormattedMicroTime($timestamp = false) {
    if(!$timestamp)
        $timestamp = microtime(true);
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u',sprintf('%.f', $timestamp))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u');
}
```

This is how I call it (I'm calling it only from one point in my code):

```
$microtime = microtime(true);
$sinceLastLog = number_format($microtime - self::$lastLogTime,4);
self::$lastLogTime = $microtime;
return Utils::GetFormattedMicroTime($microtime) .'|'. $sinceLastLog .'| blah blah';
```

And I'm getting a lot of:

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Can anybody help me troubleshoot?

EDIT:

I'm using php-fpm 5.4.28

i've changed my function a bit:

```
public static function GetFormattedMicroTime($timestamp = false) {
    if(!$timestamp)
        $timestamp = microtime(true);

    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u',sprintf('%.f', $timestamp));
    if ($d instanceof DateTime){
        return $d->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u');
    } else {
        error_log("Erreur date ! timestamp = $timestamp erreur =".print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors(),true));
        return $timestamp;
    }
}
```

now i'm getting in nginx log:

```
PHP message: Erreur date ! timestamp = 1403539343,372 erreur = Array
(
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )
    [error_count] => 2
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [10] => Unexpected data found.
        )
)
```

Comment: Your date/time was invalid

Comment: You're probably trying to set a tab using `format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u')` use `\t` or `\\t`

Comment: @Fred-ii- i want a T, not a tab, like in DateTime::ISO8601

Comment: @JohnConde how can my datetime be invalid ?

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u','1403538707.536290')` doesn't work on version 5.3.0 and below. I don't know why this is however.

Comment: @Jim i'm using php 5.4

Answer (score 1):

The locale affects the output of `sprintf`. Apparently, wherever you're getting this error from has a locale that uses a comma instead of a decimal point to separate whole and fractional digits.  Essentially, it's trying to do this:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u','1403538707,536290')
```

`createFromFormat` just sees it as a decimal point character, not as the locale's decimal separator.

Try using [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) instead.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', number_format($timestamp, 6, '.', ''));
```